# visual studio code Hide some js files based on pattern?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to exclude   all js files excepts files that ends with .config.js, I tried the following but not working!

```
 "files.exclude": {
    "**/web-app/**/*.js": true,
    "**/web-app/**/*.config.js": false, <-- **Keep those files**  */
}
```

Comment: I believe you are running into this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/869 As of VSCode 1.8 there unfortunately is no easy way around this since we do not support negation in globs

Comment: Thanks @MattBierner yes It's the same issue, as you said there is no way to achieve this! (surprising!! )